# Inheritance in designing mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inheritance, entity-relationship

I am learning cakePHP and I can define model relationship according to their correspondent table relationship in the database in the model classes with special class properties like `$hasOne`, `$hasMany`, `$belongsTo` etc. Now should I define my tables and their relationship the way like we do in PHP with super classes and child classes with inheritance or not?

for example a company have customers and there is a table for customers named `customers` and the company provides different services for each customer like web design, providing shared hosting, selling domain names and etc.
here services are from different types some of the fields are the same like `customer_id`, `cost`, `activation_date`, `expiration_date` etc, and there are some specific fields like `host_space`, `domain_name`, `host_type`, `design_type`, `control_panel`...

should I create a base table `services` for all of the services entries and one table for each kind of service like `domains` and specific information about domain services would store in it - `one-to-one` relation - 
OR
create a separate table per service so there is no `service` table anymore?
Thanks

Comment: why? Is there any problem with cake?

Comment: It might be a waste of time. And yes, there are many problems with cake. However I won't stop you to do whatever you want, I just was wondering.

Answer (score 1):

> Now should I define my tables and their relationship the way like we
>   do in PHP with super classes and child classes with inheritance or
>   not?

No, because you cannot use inheritance in MySQL. It uses the relational database paradigm. Inheritance is a concept used in object-oriented programming.

> should I create a base table services for all of the services entries
>   and one table for each kind of service like domains and specific
>   information about domain services would store in it - one-to-one
>   relation

Yes, this is exactly what you should do. Have a base table containing the columns that are consistent across all types of services, adding extra tables for the extra data.

You may even be able to divide your services further into service groups if you find additional duplicated columns.

Comment: oh! my perspective from doing the same with OOP concept was that creating a base table and other tables for different information.. Thanks for your guide